# menu lateral com margem left

Tags: html, css, menu

Tenho uma `div` central e uma `div` para colocar o menu. O problema é que tá com uma margem left que não consigo tirar de maneira alguma. Acredito que seja por conta do style do `UL`.

https://jsfiddle.net/kar5hfxk/

[image: RESULTADO]

Comment: Coloca `margin: 0` e `padding: 0` no `UL`

Comment: Obrigado Gumball. Ajudou demais! :)

Comment: Fé no Pai que o inimigo cai!

Answer (score 2):

analisando seu código o que esta faltando é zerar o margin e padding da tag ul, segue o código:

```css
.cardt {
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0 0 1px rgba(63, 63, 68, 0.1);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  
}  
  .panoramamoedas{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
  }

.panoramamoedas ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panoramamoedas ul li {
  display: block;
  backgroun: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  text-align: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.panoramamoedas a:link {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.panoramamoedas a:hover {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  color: #039;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardt">
  <div class="panoramamoedas" >
    <ul>

      <li><a href="link1.htm">teste</a></li>
      <li><a href="link1.htm">teste2</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Copiou do meu comentário.

Comment: @Gumball Não, foi ao mesmo tempo! Não respondi com base no seu comentário, sinto muito se deu a entender.

Comment: Não, agora vou te processar por cópia de informação.

Comment: @Gumball kkkkkkk